# TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function $("#partipnt-name").autocomplete({

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, fullcalendar

[image]

I'm working on this full calendar jquery plugin. When I run the project I got this  **TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function** error.

I changed jquery.ui.css, jquery.js and jquery-ui.js order too.. But it didn't give a result. 

**Please this is not a repeating question.** Help me..

```
<head>
        <meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <link href='resource/css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='resource/css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>
        <link href='resource/css/metro.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='resource/css/metro-responsive.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='resource/css/select2.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='resource/css/metro-icons.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='resource/css/metro-bootsrap.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href="resource/css/iconFonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="resource/css/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='resource/css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


        <script src='resource/js/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='resource/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src='resource/js/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='resource/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script src='resource/js/metro.js'></script>
        <script src='resource/js/select2_locale_en.js'></script>
        <script src="resource/js/select2.js"></script>
        <script src="resource/js/datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="resource/js/calendar.js"></script>

        <script src="resource/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                    function log(message) {
                        $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
                    }

                    $("#partipnt-name").autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "AgentController",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    q: request.term
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
            <%--var dtarr=[];--%>
            <%--$.each(data, function(index) {--%>
            <%--dtarr.push("<div>"+data[index].v_agent_id+":"+data[index].v_agent_name+"</div>");--%>
            <%--});--%>
            <%--response(dtarr);--%>

                                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                        return {
                                            label: item.v_agent_name,
                                            value: item.v_agent_name,
                                            agtid: item.v_agent_id
                                        };
                                    }));
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        minLength: 1,
                        select: function(event, ui) {
            <%--alert(ui.item.abc);--%>

            <%--log(ui.item ?--%>
            <%--" " +ui.item.value :--%>
            <%--"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);--%>
                            if (($('#meeting_date').val() == '') || $('#start_time').val() == '' || $('#end_time').val() == '') {
                                alert('Please select correct date and time before proceed');
                            } else {


                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'ParticipentController',
                                    dataType: 'JSON',
                                    data: {type: '1', prtid: ui.item.agtid, meetingdate: $('#meeting_date').val(), stattime: $('#start_time').val(), endtime: $('#end_time').val()},
                                    success: function(data) {




                                        if (new String(data[0].result).valueOf() == new String('true').valueOf()) {
                                            $("#log").append("<li class='select2-search-choice' aid='" + ui.item.agtid + "'>" + "<div style='color:green'>" + ui.item.value + "</div>" + "" + "</li>");
                                        } else {

                                            $("#log").append("<li class='select2-search-choice' aid='" + ui.item.agtid + "'>" + "<div style='color:red'>" + ui.item.value + "</div>" + "" + "</li>");
                                        }

                                    }

                                });
                            }



            <%--$("#partipnt-name").value("");--%>

                        },
                        open: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                        },
                        close: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                        }
                    });





        </script>

        <script>



            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                        //--------Show Meeting Page
                        if (calEvent.page === "M") {
                            showDialog('#dialog1');

                            $('#d1location').val(calEvent.v_location);
                            $('#d1meeting_type').val(calEvent.v_category_name);
                            $('#d1description').val(calEvent.v_description);
                            $('#d1subject').val(calEvent.v_subject);
                            $('#hid_meeting_id').val(calEvent.id);
                            $('#meetinghed').html("Meeting Detail :" + calEvent.v_subject);


                            if (calEvent.n_status_ID !== 1) {
                                $('#myhid').hide();
                            } else {
                                $('#myhid').show();
                            }

                            if (${sessionScope["ownership"]}) {
                                $('#myhid').show();

                            } else {
                                $('#myhid').hide();
                            }
//                            if (calEvent.creater === true) {
//
//                                $('#myhid').hide();
//
//                            } else {
//                                $('#myhid').show();
//                            }


                            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                        }

                        //--------Show Event Page
                        if (calEvent.page === "E") {
                            showDialog('#event_dialog');

                            $('#event_type').val(calEvent.v_category_name);
                            $('#event_description_dialog').val(calEvent.v_description);
                            $('#event_subject_dialog').val(calEvent.v_subject);
                            $('#hid_event_id').val(calEvent.id);
                            $('#eventhed').html("Event Detail :" + calEvent.v_subject);
                            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
                        }
                    },
                    minTime: '07:00:00',
                    maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    defaultTime: '08am',
                    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                    events: {
                        url: 'CalenderController',
                        error: function() {
                            $('#script-warning').show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Is the console telling you which file that error is coming form? Stack traces are often helpful here. By the looks of it you have something trying to call a jQuery plugin, but that plugin is not loaded yet (or never gets loaded).

Comment: @NathanaelSmith I added image of console.

Comment: @NathanaelSmith I changed the code. Please take a look at that.

Comment: I think, you are not including the good library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error in the console is coming because select2 is not defined on jQuerys's protype. Move select2 above the select2 localization.

```
<script src="resource/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src='resource/js/select2_locale_en.js'></script>
```

Comment: What you want to see?

Comment: uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2 s2id_meeting
TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
 

$("#partipnt-name").autocomplete({